# SwipeGestureRecognizer is not working after using PanGesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using **PanGestureRecognizer** to my `self.view` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in my `UITableView`.
I have added `UITableView` as subview in `self.view`.
Now `UISwipeGesture` is not working.
But if i disable PanGesture in `self.view`, SwipeGesture is working.

Can someone solve this?

Comment: have you enabled userInteraction?

Comment: Got the answer through these links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111828/how-to-have-a-uiswipegesturerecognizer-and-uipangesturerecognizer-work-on-the-sa

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801721/pinch-rotate-uigesturerecognizerdelegate-not-called

Comment: Yes. I have enabled. Just failed to call "shouldrecognizesimultaneouslywithgesturerecognizer" this delegate method to run multiple gestureRecognizers

Answer (score 1):

Go through this stackoverflow question's answer to get an idea about swipe and pan gestures...

[What is the difference between Pan and Swipe in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898627/what-is-the-difference-between-pan-and-swipe-in-ios)

hope this will helps you...